# Finding int within a int?

Tags: java

I need to find the indices of `int` A is within `String` B, for example, given:

A: 53 and B: "1953786"

should return 2.

Without using a built in function such as indexOf... The length of the string can be of any length, what sort of algorithm would suit such a search?

Comment: Convert to string, run indexof.

Comment: That is not a very large integer, sir.

Comment: Why the downvotes? It might not obvious to a newbie that he may convert the problem to Strings.

Comment: The idea wasnt to use a built in function, i should have made it clear...

Comment: @Lunar Is this homework?

Comment: No its not home work, its just a simple programming challenge.

Comment: @Lunar: Regardless whether it's homework or a programming challenge, there is clearly a specific reason you're not allowed to use indexOf - that can either be because they expect you to implement your *own* indexOf for strings, or because you're supposed to do it mathematically (using base 10 logarithms, integer division and modulo). We don't know which of those it is.

Comment: It's easy to write a method yourself that does the same as `String.indexOf`, if you're not allowed to use that.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
Integer.toString(b).indexOf(Integer.toString(a))
```

Answer (score 3):

Use  [Integer.toString(int myinteger)](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/java/lang/Integer.html#toString%28int%29)  method of Integer class to get the String representation of integer.

```
 int i = 1953786;
 int j = 53;
 String str1  = Integer.toString(i);
 String str2 = Integer.toString(j);
 int idx = str1.indexOf(str2);
 System.out.println(idx);
```

Output = `2`

Answer (score 2):

```
B.toString().indexOf(A.toString());
```

Comment: -1 : it will give compilation error. Just try it. See my or @beny23 's answer.

Comment: Of course I was assuming `Integer`, beny23's answer works fine if you assume `int`. It doesn't change the idea anyway.

Comment: I figured that you were assuming `Integer` but OP wants `int`.